# How to interface with beings in the galactic core?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, space, black-holes

### Context:

So assume there are an unknown number of near-omnipotent/omniscient beings who have been confirmed to live inside of an area of space called the [Active Galactic Nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_galactic_nucleus) (AGN). To provide a little more color:

- The AGN can belong to any galaxy, it need not be the Milky Way's galactic core.
- The beings inside the AGN **require** the intense gravity from accretion & extreme radiation to survive.
- The beings inside of the AGN send pulses of information at extreme intervals (usually pulses are >5M years apart.)
- These pulses contain what we would call "prophecies," in that each decoded pulse contains a prediction which happens with 100% observed accuracy.

### So question time:

**How** would a spacefaring race with arbitrarily advanced technology attempt to make contact with these creatures? What sort of things would they try? What would be the largest limitation in their attempts to communicate?

Comment: Some clarifying questions: What kind precision are we talking about? Would a prophecy we received today warn us about a plane crash, a limited nuclear exchange, a Coronal Mass Ejection that wipes out all life on Earth, or a Supernovae explosion that would sterilize a significant hunk of the local spiral arm? Are these prophecies specific to recipient societies, or is the entire galaxy getting the same message? Does the answer need to assume that the beings in question have any need, desire, or even ability to respond to direct contact even if they notice it?

Comment: 1. Extremely high precision for the things they predict (there is no escaping them). 2. It usually would be a warning about some cosmic event which, unless prepared for, would wipe out all life in the galaxy or some segment of the galaxy. 3. Sometimes specific, always to preserve sentient life. 4. The pulses are just normal quasar ejections but less-random. 5. No, answer need not assume anything about the beings' motivations; in fact it's unsure if they are benevolent gods, uncaring custodians, or a maybe even just a computer on a timer.

Comment: question, a quasar is a ring of gas around a black hole.... So you need to go a bit more into detail on what these beings use to communicate if you want us to device a technology that could communicate with them. Is it in some code or energy or what exactly is this ejection made of?

Comment: @WolvesEyes - Thank you for that correction. These are what I'm talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet

Comment: If 5m years between statements is conversational speeds for these aliens, entire species would go their creation to extinction cycles without knowing they were there, or receiving the answer to an inquiry being sent.

Comment: @pojo-guy Sure! Maybe most would.

Answer (score 2):

> How would a spacefaring race with arbitrarily advanced technology attempt to make contact with these creatures?

Whatever form of energy the prophecies are being sent in, would be the primary method anybody would use to try to talk back. If you want something that will be visible throughout the galaxy, you want something that's not going to be occluded or distorted by intervening matter if you happen to be out on the edge or something. Neutrinos or similar would be my first choice for what the Core Beings would use to communicate, and would be what anybody trying to communicate back would probably use.

> What sort of things would they try?

The prophecies give you a rosetta stone of sorts, if you can decode them, you know how the Core Beings communicate. You wouldn't stray very far from the same energies and modulations that the Core Beings themselves use to communicate to avoid the risk of trying something else (like gravitational waves) that might be percieved as an attack.

> What would be the largest limitation in their attempts to communicate?

I would say the biggest challenge would be even getting the Core Beings to notice. Or care. If they're omniscient and benevolent, they're already sharing the information that they can and desire to share, so there's no reason they'd be inclined to provide additional detail just because someone is able to ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably they would need to use whatever the "pulses" are made of if they wanted to get in contact. Maybe gravity waves? I think probably the biggest limit to their communication is time scale, cause it could take an entire generation to get an answer. And that's assuming there is an answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

So, these ejections are of ionized atoms,
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization

And there are positive and negative ions, which could be used as binary 1s and 0s, creating the language they speak. 
Having said this, also look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling
Which may allow data or ionized atoms from your pulses to be sent at faster speeds than the speed of light.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-beam_weapon
Possibly used to shoot particles to communicate, It could be used to only shoot certain types of particles and if developed enough to do this rapidly in a binary like code.

I'm not fully certain on detection or if it is possible yet, here are some links that may help.
https://ehss.energy.gov/ohre/roadmap/achre/intro_9_1.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaUHQBtugU
https://www.britannica.com/science/ionization
https://www.chemguide.co.uk/analysis/masspec/howitworks.html
https://sciencing.com/calculate-ionization-energy-atoms-6632496.html

Side note, Depending on the charge or type of atom you could make it more complex than binary with other negative and positive atom types giving you more complex data in possibly smaller packages like 0s 1s 2s and 3s instead of just 1s and 0s